# Animated tree navigation using Vue & Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, animation, nuxt.js, page-transition

I'm starting to learn a few basics with nuxt & vue.
I'm basically building a little list of elements that you can click and will expand with an image or some other content.

## What I made so far

is an homepage with the list (like the first image)
and 3 other pages : /about, /projects, /contact

Here is the demo with images :

[image: the homepage when you enter the website]

As soon as I click the first link, an image appears, and everything is moved down to the bottom. The URL is updated with the corresponding url (here, /about)
[image: the page if you navigate to /about]

## What I would like to achieve:

So far it's working fine and I can naviguate on my website.
But as the images suggests, I would like the differents elements of the menu to move with an animation to the bottom on the page transition to the different pages, it would take them (let's say) 2 seconds to go their next position in the next page.

It would look something like that : https://codepen.io/pbouigue/pen/KKVxbYa
when you click a dropdown menu like `first video`the menu expends and everything is moved down.
**The issue with that** is that the url is not updated and considered to move to another page (in the case it should be `exemple.com/first-video`

```html
<template>
 <div class="container">

  <transition-group name="list">
    <nuxt-link to="about" key="about">First item - about</nuxt-link>
    <img src="../assets/ours.png" alt="">
    //these two remaining items should have an animation when they move to the bottom of the image
    <nuxt-link to="projects" key="projects">Second item - projects</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="contact" key="contact">Last item - contact</nuxt-link>
  <transition-group>
 </div>
</template>

<style >
img{
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
}

a{
    display: block;
    color: orangered;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
</style>
```

and my /about :

```html
<template>
 <div class="container">

  <transition-group name="list">
    <nuxt-link to="about" key="about">First item - about</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="projects" key="projects">Second item - projects</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="contact" key="contact">Last item - contact</nuxt-link>
  <transition-group>
 </div>
</template>

<style >
img{
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
}

a{
    display: block;
    color: orangered;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
</style>
```

Do you have any help on how to achieve that? Maybe there is an easier way to do it, but since I'm all new and learning by myself, I would have loved some clues or a little help.

I read about transition-group and this css, but somehow, I can't manage to make it work...

```css
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.list-enter-from,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

because actually this :https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#move-transitions
does exactly what i would like to do : move elements down in an animation, but I would like this to happen on a page transition in order to have to url updated.

Maybe I should look for https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html ?

Comment: Not sure if you read that one already: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html What kind of transition do you want exactly? Give that one a try. Also, there are a few changes between Vue2 and Vue3 so you may refer to Vue2's documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#ad

Comment: Oh and I forgot, but this is how to make some transitions in Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-transition#transition-properties Basically following the same basics as in Vue but applied easily to pages.

Comment: I read vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html but actually, it helped me to make a transition of all the elements in the page (like a fade-in, zoom...) which I managed to do. Here, I would like to have a seemless page transition with the 2 list items moving down, taking a few second to reach the next position on the next page.

Comment: Something like this so: https://github.com/antfu/vue-starport ? Using FLIP animations.

Comment: Exactly!
I'm going to dig that!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want to achieve and the amount of code you want to write. GSAP can be used, it's quite powerful: https://greensock.com/3-9/ Otherwise, a full CSS solution is feasible too IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I still need to figure out a way to do this step by step... And to find the most efficient way.
I know there are some page transition js plugins too, that I will be able to tame well.
Still have some learning to do before nailing what I want to do with nuxt & vue. But it's exciting! :)

Comment: Yep! Stay away from jQuery or too big libraries overall and take your time to explore!